# finding number of unique outcomes of round-robin tournament with cycle

Tags: combinatorics

A round robin tournament is a tournament where each player plays other player once and there is no draw. If a team wins against all other then it is called Total Winner. Similarly we define Total Looser as a team which looses all matches.

**EDITED::**

> Let us define order by win/loss. If $A$ wins $B$ and $B$ wins $C$ then it is ordered as $\dots >A>B>C>\dots$
>   Consider $n\ge 3 $ teams, $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ games are played  and $2^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ unique results might be possible. Out of those $2^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ possible results, how many unique outcomes are there such that we can order **every** player (only once) such that it forms a cycle. i.e.
>   $$P_1 > P_2 > P_2 > \dots > P_n > P_1$$

**Some of my thoughts::**
There cannot be cycle if there is Total Winner or Total Looser. I found (by using Principle of Inclusion Exclusion) out there exists $$2^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}-(2n)2^{\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}}+n(n-1)2^{\frac{(n-3)(n-2)}{2}}$$ [possible results](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5B2%5E%28n%28n-1%29/2%29-2%20n%202%5E%28%28n-2%29%28n-1%29/2%29%2bn%28n-1%292%5E%28%28n-3%29%28n-2%29/2%29,%7Bn,%203,%206%7D%5D) of the tournament where there is no Total Winner or no Total looser.

**ADDED::**  I wrote a [short script](http://pastebin.com/trnj4G1c) for total matches outcomes and outcomes with no total winner or looser. But couldn't write more to detect cycles. For $n=3$ & $n=4$, all  matches where there is no total winner or total looser have some sort of cycles.

**ADDED::**

Here is [updated code](http://ideone.com/wgJvyb).
If three players played game, player $(1), (2)$, and $(3)$ the outcomes are

> [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]  $ \leftarrow (1)$ is total winner so there can't be cycle.
>   [(1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 2)]
>   [(1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 3)]
>   [(1, 2), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
>   [(2, 1), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
>   [(2, 1), (1, 3), (3, 2)]
>   [(2, 1), (3, 1), (2, 3)]
>   [(2, 1), (3, 1), (3, 2)]

Here, $(1,2)$ means match was played by $(1)$ and $(2)$ and $(1)$ won the game.

The following forms a cycle (also it is the only outcome where there are no total winner and total looser)

> [(1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 3)] $ \implies 1>2>3>1$
>   [(2, 1), (1, 3), (3, 2)] $\implies 1>3>2>1$

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Your question is now even less clear than it was originally. Exactly what are you trying to count? All $n$-player tournaments that have no $n$-cycle?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I am trying to count the unique results of the tournament with cycles. Here is the [list](http://ideone.com/wgJvyb) of possible outcomes. $(a,b)$ means $a$ played agaist $(b)$ and $a$ won.

Comment: If by *cycle* you mean $n$-cycle, a cycle containing all of the players, then you’re trying to count the $n$-player tournaments that have an $n$-cycle.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yes that it is. sorry If I mislead you before.

Comment: Okay; that looks a bit messy, but I’ll give it some thought.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott sure, anytime you find free, this used to homework question that i got little extra curious.

Answer (score 2):

In graph theory, the default meaning of the word [*tournament*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_%28graph_theory%29) is round-robin tournament. I.e., a tournament is an oriented complete graph; each pair of distinct *vertices* (*nodes, players*) is joined by a single directed edge in one direction; a directed edge $xy$ means that player x *beats* player y. In the context of tournaments (or more general directed graphs), the words *path* and *cycle* refer to **directed** paths and cycles. If $T$ is a tournament on $n$ vertices, a *Hamiltonian cycle* in $T$ is a cycle of length $n$, i.e., a cycle that contains all the vertices. Your question asks, of the $2^{\binom{n}{2}}=2^{n(n-1)/2}$ different tournaments on $n$ labeled vertices, how many have a Hamiltonian cycle?

Let's call two vertices $x$ and $y$ "equivalent" if there is a path from $x$ to $y$ and also a path from $y$ to $x$. It's easy to see that this is an equivalence relation; the equivalence classes are called the *strong components* of the tournament. The tournament is said to be [*strongly connected*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensation_%28graph_theory%29) if all vertices are equivalent, i.e., if there is just one strong component. This notion is related to your question because of the following theorem. (The case $n=1$ is exceptional because, while a tournament on one node is strongly connected, it does not have a Hamiltonian cycle.)

**Theorem 1.** A tournament $T$ on $n$ vertices ($n\gt1$) has a Hamiltonian cycle if and only if it is strongly connected.

**Proof.** The "only if" is clear: if $T$ has a Hamiltonian cycle, then it is strongly connected. I will sketch a proof of the converse.

Suppose T is strongly connected; we have to show that $T$ has a Hamiltonian cycle. We start by showing that $T$ has a cycle, not necessarily of length $n$. Choose a directed edge $uv$. Since $T$ is strongly connected, there is a path from $v$ to $u$; this path, together with the edge $uv$, gives us a cycle in $T$.

Let $C$ be a cycle in $T$ of maximum length $m$; we have to show that $m=n$. Let $W$ (for "winners") be the set of all players that beat at least one player in $C$, i.e., $v\in W$ iff there is a directed edge from $v$ to some vertex in $C$. Similarly, let $L$ (for "losers") be the set of all players beaten by at least one player in $C$, i.e., $v\in L$ iff there is a directed edge to $v$ from some vertex in $C$. We consider several cases.

Case 1. $W=\emptyset=L$.

In this case, the cycle $C$ contains all vertices of $T$, and everything is fine. We shall see that each of the other cases leads to a contradiction.

Case 2. $W=\emptyset\ne L$.

Then $C$ has no "incoming" edges. If $u\in L$ and $v\in C$, then there is no path from $u$ to $v$, contradicting the assumption that $T$ is strongly connected.

Case 3. $W\ne\emptyset=L$.

If $u\in C$ and $v\in W$, then there is no path from $u$ to $v$, contradicting the assumption that $T$ is strongly connected.

Case 4. $W\cap L\ne\emptyset$.

If $v\in W\cap L$, then we can insert $v$ between two consecutive vertices of $C$ so as to obtain a cycle of length $m+1$, contradicting the assumed maximality of $m$.

Case 5. $W\ne\emptyset$, $L\ne\emptyset$, and $W\cap L=\emptyset$.

Since $T$ is strongly connected, there must be a directed edge $uv$ for some $u\in L$, $v\in W$. Then the vertices $u,v$ can be inserted in the cycle $C$ so as to obtain a cycle of length $m+2$, contradicting the assumed maximality of $m$. **Q.E.D.**

Thus, your question is equivalent to determining $a(n)$, the number of strongly connected labeled tournaments on $n$ vertices. This function is sequence number [A054946](http://oeis.org/A054946) at the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/), the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. There you can find various information about this sequence, including references, tabulated values, and the following recurrence formula. Let $F(n)=2^{\binom{n}{2}}=2^{n(n-1)/2}$. Then (for $n\gt0$)$$F(n)=\sum_{s=1}^n\binom{n}{s}a(s)F(n-s).$$The recurrence is explained by the following structural property of tournaments:

**Theorem 2.** A nonempty tournament $T$ has a uniquely determined subtournament $S$ such that $S$ is nonempty and strongly connected, and each player in $S$ beats all players outside of $S$. Namely, $S$ consists of all players $u$ such that, for each $v\in T$, there is a path from $u$ to $v$.

Let's call the set $S$ in Theorem 2 the "top component" of $T$. (I don't know if it has an official name.) Now the meaning of the recurrence is clear: the term $\binom{n}{s}a(s)F(n-s)$ is just the number of tournaments on a set of $n$ labeled players whose top component has size $s$. Namely, there are $\binom{n}{s}$ ways to choose the elements of the top component $S$, then $a(s)$ ways to define a strongly connected tournament on the set $S$, and $F(n-s)$ ways to define a tournament on the set $T\setminus S$; of course, the edges between $S$ and $T\setminus S$ are all directed away from $S$.

Comment: Are you implying that if there are no total winners and no total losers, then there exists some cycle? It seems true for $n=3$ and $n=4$. I think this sequence can be generated by [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table[2^%28n%28n-1%29/2%29-2%20n%202^%28%28n-2%29%28n-1%29/2%29%2bn%28n-1%292^%28%28n-3%29%28n-2%29/2%29,{n,%203,%206}])

Comment: If by "cycle" you mean "cycle of length $n$", then no, I'm not implying that. Suppose $n=6$, call the teams A, B, C, D, E, F. Suppose that A beats B, B beats C, C beats A, D beats E, E beats F, F beats D, and suppose that A, B, C win all their games against D, E, F. There is no total winner, no total loser (each team scores either 4-1 or 1-4); there are two 3-cycles, but there is no 6-cycle.

Comment: I am looking for $n$-cycle in how many outcomes of all possible outcomes can I find $n$-cycle?

Comment: sorry ... my mistake earlier. (+1), would you add what is the idea behind this sequence? I don't have any experience with graph theory. just a little outline. this is just discrete math problem gone little bad. And i also thought I could solve it using combinatotics.

Comment: if you feel too long to type then, please give me some references, i'll have to read it anyway to understand it.

Comment: @hasExams The formula follows easily from setting up the recurrance relation.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: For $k=1,\ldots,n$ let $w_k$ be the number of matches won by Team $k$. If there is no cycle, the tournament is transitive: if Team $j$ beats Team $k$ and Team $k$ beats Team $\ell$, then Team $j$ beats Team $\ell$. There must also be a Total Winner. Use these facts to prove by induction on $n$ that $$\{w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n\}=\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}\;:$$ one team wins all of its matches, another loses only to the Total Winner, another loses only to those top two teams, and so on down to a Total Loser. In other words, if there is no cycle, the teams can be completely ranked by their scores: for each possible score from $0$ wins through $n-1$ wins there is exactly one team with that score.

Once you have that, it’s easy to count the tournaments with no cycle, and you already know the total number of tournaments, so you can easily get the number of tournaments that have at least one cycle.

Comment: hmm ... given that there no total winner or total looser, does it always contain at least one cycle? If there is total winner or total looser, that is dead end. But other case (with no total winner or looser), I am having difficulty to prove it. I think this assertion is wrong or my eyes are not working well.

Comment: @hasExams: Yes. Start with any team $T_1$; $T_1$ is not a total loser (note spelling!), so it beats some team $T_2$. Similarly, $T_2$ beats some $T_3$. There are only finitely many teams, so eventually you reach a $T_k$ that is the same as $T_j$ for some $j<k$. The teams $T_j,T_{j+1},\ldots,T_{k-1}$ then form a cycle. You can do the same sort of thing if there is no total winner.

Comment: I think i forgot to specify one thing ... the cycle has to visit vertex only once and it must visit all vertex. I am sorry if I didn't mention that earlier in my question.

Comment: Your question isn’t really very clear. I couldn’t tell whether you were asking for the number of tournaments that contain some cycle, or for the number that **are** cycles. Is it the latter that you want?