# Soccer Tournament Statement to Symbolic Forms

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, induction

Suppose there is a tournament involving $b$ teams where $b \ge 2$. It is viable to name the teams as $T_1, T_2, \cdots T_b$ so that $T_r$ beats $T_{r+1}$ for any $r$ from $1$ to $b-1$.

Here is what I've done

$\forall r \in \{1,\cdots, b-1\}$, $T_r$ beats $T_{r+1}\iff b \ge 2$

Is this the correct way to write the symbolic form of the above statement?

Comment: I have two questions: Are there $b$ teams or $n$ teams? (I guess $b$). Why is the claim that any team on the list beats the next team on the list equivalent to $b\geq 2$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that every tournament contains at least one Hamiltonian path.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1682492/prove-that-every-tournament-contains-at-least-one-hamiltonian-path)

Comment: yes @Mankind it's supposed to be _b_ what I'm trying to say in symbolic form is that for all _r_ from _1_ to _b-1_ Tr _beats_ Tr+1 iff b is more than 2. _b_ is more than or equal to two is because to have a match we need 2 or more teams. From the textbook it says it's a round robin theory

Comment: thank you for the link @MikeEarnest. After reading the link I'm still at lost though, is the symbolic for of the statement I wrote above is correct or on the right path?

Comment: Not really, no. The statement in English is: "**For all** $b\ge 2$ and **for all** tournaments with $b$ teams **there exists** a list $T_1,\dots,T_b$ such that **for all** $r\in \{1,2,\dots,b-1\}$, $T_r$ beats $T_{r+1}$. So you are missing several $\forall$'s and $\exists$'s, and the $\iff$ is not right.

Comment:  thank you for the reply @MikeEarnest. I'm curious though, why is the ⟺ isn't right? Isn't the ⟺ means if and only if? why is it not suitable to use it for this statement? :D

Comment: No, $\iff$ is not right. If and only if would mean that $b<2$ implies something, but we are not saying anything in the case $b<2$.